# Show command line output in flask webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm making a script that runs a command line and then shows the output in flask webpage.

The problem I'm facing is that the output is malformed, it looks like this.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiBoL.jpg)

here's my what I have wrote so far:

```
import subprocess as sp

@app.route('/harvester/scan',methods=['GET','POST'])
def harv():
    domain=request.values.get('domain')
    outputt=sp.getoutput("theharvester" + " " + "-d" + " " + domain + " " + "-l 10 -b all"  )
    return outputt
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Function `subprocess.getoutput` is a legacy one. Try using `subprocess.run` instead.

Here is the example:

```py
import subprocess

command = 'printf "1\n2"'
out = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
```